# Special Case with CodeIgniter Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I've got a mostly static site. My default controller handles most views in it's `index` action, simply passing the `$this->uri->segment(1)` through to my template.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'master';
$route['(:any)'] = 'master';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

But now I'm implementing a new controller that I would like to have default behavior. And I don't want to be sullying up my routes config with superfluous routes for every single action. So how can I say, route anything to the default `master` controller except for `NewController`, which you should handle normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `404_override` route location to handle your wildcard pages. That way you won't need to define every existing controller/method that you create.

Just make sure that the `404_override` controller/method then correctly outputs an HTTP 404 header, and any appropriate output for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you mean but if I understand you correctly if you add the line

```
$route['NewController'] = 'NewController';
```

In before the (:any) route it should load it first.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'master';
$route['NewController'] = 'NewController';
$route['(:any)'] = 'master';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: It seems like that would work right? I tried that. `NewController/action` gets sent to `master`.

Comment: That route would only handle a URI with a single `NewController` segment (btw, avoid capitalization in routes and controller names - controllers should be `ucwords` format). You'd need to add additional logic for anything after NewController, such as `localhost/newcontroller/method/param`.

Comment: Right... Unfortunately that's what I was trying to avoid.